# How can i add a woocommerce success-notice, on the "my account" page - for a specific user role?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a discount notice for newly registered "customers" who have not yet made a purchase by hooking into `woocommerce_account_content`. Tried building the code myself by combining a bunch of different code. Troubles are:

1: Never got the notice to display at all.

2: Gave upp when i realized woocommerce didn't have a subscriber role - is there a way to display it only to customers with 0 orders?

This is as far as i got (not functioning):

```
add_action('woocommerce_account_content','new-customer-discount-notice');
    global $user_login, $current_user;

        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);

            if (in_array('customer', $user_info->roles)) {
                wc_add_notice( 'Congratulations! You have a 10% new customer discount! Valid for 48 hours.', 'success' );
    }
}
```

Current code at the moment does nothing, I'm a bit of a newb with php to be honest. Included it anyway as it might help you see what I'm trying to accomplish. (Don't laugh too hard)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Think i got it working after alot of struggle! Updating here should anyone be attempting to do the same.

```
function new_customer_discount_notice() {

    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
    ) );


    $notice_text = sprintf( 'Congratulations! You have a 10% new customer discount! Valid for 48 hours.' );

    if ( ! count( $customer_orders ) ) {
        wc_print_notice( $notice_text, 'success' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', 'new_customer_discount_notice' );
```

Still haven't figured out how to make the text only visible for the first 48 hours though, but at the moment I'm satisfied.